# Controlls are not displaying in interface builder?

Tags: iphone

i am facing a problem with IBOutlet,please Respected developers help me out, as i am fresher in iphone

for eg.
i declared buttons or controls with IBOutlet in .h file ,but many times interface builder is not showing the controls so i use to exit the application and reopen it again and i found it
so is there any thing i am missing.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Did you save your files? A mistake a lot of people new to iOS/Mac development don't realize is that Interface Builder will not show the IBOutlets unless you have saved the files first. So anytime you add an IBOutlet, make sure you save your header file before diving into Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

How are you declaring your outlets? Also, what do you mean by "interface builder is not showing the **controls**"? If you have the following code:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
     IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
     IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
}
// Properties
// Methods
@end
```

In IB's connection inspector the outlets should show up and allow you to connect them to valid UI objects. Could you please clarify your issue?